# iOS Add multiple optional value in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift

```
var a: CGFloat!  
var b: CGFloat!  
var c: CGFloat!
```

After init then

```
let x = a + b + c
```

The Xcode8 would show

***Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat' and 'CGFloat!'***

guess first add two of them made this Error

Maybe I could use first add one and then add third to fix

But It will change my x to var and not concise as past

Any Suggestion?

---

*Edit: there must some application scenarios we could faced, I wrote this simple demo just 4 express this issue :)*

Comment: should you not be doing something like this var a: CGFloat?  instead of var a: CGFloat!       ?

Comment: Seems to be a bug for me. Simple workaround `let x = 0 + a + b + c`.

Comment: @UmairAfzal I use forcing unpackage (!) for convenience(too much of unnecessary let x = optional always be boring :( ), And since this syntax still not deprecated. I think there should be a concise way to do this ... :)

Comment: As you're finding, implicitly unwrapped optionals are becoming less convenient. This is intentional (if it weren't for Cocoa bridging, they would certainly not even be available). They should not be common in your code. If you're constantly having to unwrap optionals, it is very likely you have too many optionals. For example, you clearly expect `a`, `b` and `c` to all be available or all not be available. If that's true, then they should be in a struct. The struct can then be optional if necessary (though every optional should be questioned; they tend to be wildly overused).

Comment: If you don't want to use optionals, just use simple `CGFloat`s, then you're guaranteed there will be no crashes from accessing a nil value and you'll need no `if let`s. But as Rob Napier says, implicitly unwrapped optionals exist mostly for compatibility with Interface Builder and older stuff; they are not meant to be used without care.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding a + b produces CGFloat, and then compiler not sure how to add c, which is of type CGFloat!

If you define c as `var c: CGFloat = 0`(just for experiment) - same code will compile.

I found two more ways of summing this 3 variables:

```
let x = a.advanced(by: b + c)
```

or

```
let y = CGFloat(a + b) + c
```

Both looks not cool as for me, but at least compiler now understand how to add those values.
Maybe this is Swift bug, and will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
import CoreGraphics

var a: CGFloat! = 1
var b: CGFloat! = 2
var c: CGFloat! = 3

if let a:CGFloat=a, let b:CGFloat=b, let c:CGFloat=c
{
    let x = a + b + c
}
else
{
    print("at least one of them was nil")
}
```

Defining them as `CGFloat!` says that they're optionals, but you know they will contain a value at the point that you will use them.

`let a:CGFloat=a` unwraps a into a new CGFloat (not CGFloat! - the new one isn't optional)

That is a runtime error if it doesn't contain a value, so the `if` handles that situation.

Note that the `a` inside the body of the if hides the one outside - it's not the same object.

Also note that you don't need the types where you unwrap them - they'll automatically be `CGFloat` (Thanks @NRitH)

Comment: There's no need to specify the `:CGFloat` in each of the `if let` expressions.